# Firebase: update user's profile not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am updating the Firebase user profile photoURL 
it's upadted in the store but not in the Firebase users db... 
when I signout then signin with this user, the photoURL is NOT changed

here is my store action

```
    updateProfilePhotoURL ({commit}, payload) {
      const updateFBUserProfile = async (commit, payload) => {
        commit(types.SET_LOADING, true)
        let db = firebase.database()
        const updatedData = {
          photoURL: payload.photoURL
        }
        // Update the Firebase user profile too...
        await db.ref('users/' + payload.uid).update(updatedData)
        // Update the store profile too...
        commit(types.UPDATE_PROFILE_PHOTO_URL, updatedData.photoURL)
        return 'ok'
      }
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        updateFBUserProfile(commit, payload)
          .then(result => {
            commit(types.SET_LOADING, false)
            resolve(result)
          }, error => {
            console.log('ERROR: ', error)
            reject(error)
          })
      })
    }
```

where am I wrong ?

thanks for feedback

Comment: do you have permissions to write to db from app? are there no errors?

Comment: @Max thanks for feedback ...  I have R/W permission at admin level ( myself@myisp.com ) in the Firebase settings .. so I created the john.doe@example user...  but john.doe itself does not have any rights... are checked credentials for updating the profile . john.doe or myself as admin ??

Comment: you can check user with `firebase.auth().currentUser`. But I don't think you use `firebase-admin` module  in client app, so I think your user has no rights write to db. You can open your firebase console -> database -> <your-database> -> "rules" tab -> set write to `true` for debug.

Comment: @Max thanks a lot !   forgot it ... after reading your comment , I read the 'Understanding the power of Firebase security rules" ( https://medium.com/@dftaiwo/understanding-the-power-of-firebase-security-rules-part-1-f46aae773a24 ) . got it !!!  You should answer the question ... I'll vote for it !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to question comments - I think your user has no permissions to write to db. You can check it with `firebase.auth().currentUser` or check your Rules for database in Firebase Console.